# Check if input value exist from unique input name

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have an html input text like this :

```
<input type="text" name="address[5][firstname]">
```

i want to check if the value is exist only by input which contain a specific string like **firstname**. Here's what i've done so far:

```
if($( "input[name*='[firstname]']" ).length < 1){
   console.log('in');
}

if($( "input[name*='[firstname]']" ).length < 1){
   console.log('in');
}
```

Comment: Could you be specific? What do you want to do? Also, observe your console for any errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i want to check if the value is exist only by input which contain a specific string like firstname

Your selector is good but your `if` condition is wrong. You are checking `< 1` but there is already an element matched and length is `1`, hence the condition not satisfied. Change it to `> 0`

```
if($( "input[name*='[firstname]']" ).length > 0){
  alert('in');
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sureshatta/tuwdzgue/